# How do I find next and previous months across the change of year

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having two text boxes(startdate,enddate).
If The startdate and enddate values are between 21st of any month and 20th of next month from startDate month means, i can do anything Else not.

for example,

startdate(25/jan/2017) and enddate(20/feb/2017) : can do any logic

startdate(25/jan/2017)and enddate(21/feb/2017): not possible to do the logic

i used some logic for that,

```
if ((startDate2.Day >= 21 && endDate2.Day >= 21 && emonth == smonth) 
     || (startDate2.Day >= 21 && endDate2.Day <= 20 && emonth == smonth + 1)         
     || (startDate2.Day <= 20 && endDate2.Day <= 20 && emonth == smonth) 
     || (startDate2.Day <= 20 && endDate2.Day >= 21 && emonth == smonth - 1))
            {
            }
```

but it was not working for startdate(in December month) and endDate(in January month) because of this `((startDate2.Day <= 20 && endDate2.Day >= 21 && emonth == smonth - 1))` can anyone help me with correct logic?

Comment: Should e.g. from 8th to 15th of the same month be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are expecting the `end month` be exactly one less than the starting month

```
emonth == smonth -1
```

Which means it can't work if you compare December to January

```
1 == 12-1 => false
```

Not providing any full solutions, but want to help you little by little to understand ;)

Comment: yes you are right. the above code is well worked if it is from (21st jan to 20th dec) but not from( 21st dec to 20th jan)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `smonth`and `emonth` are `int` and define the month from `1` to `12`, you could use modulo on the months:

```
if ((startDate2.Day >= 21 && endDate2.Day >= 21 && emonth == smonth) 
     || (startDate2.Day >= 21 && endDate2.Day <= 20 && emonth == ((smonth + 2)%12)-1)         
     || (startDate2.Day <= 20 && endDate2.Day <= 20 && emonth == smonth) 
     || (startDate2.Day <= 20 && endDate2.Day >= 21 && ((emonth+2)%12)-1 == smonth))
```

Note, however, that this will still allow e.g. Dec 23 2015 until Jan 12 2017.

To avoid this, you should compare the year as well or implement an additional condition limiting `endDate-startDate` to 31 days:

```
endDate <= startDate.AddDays(31);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working. but not for the year 2016 only for (dec 2016, jan-dec 2017)

Comment: This answer is independent of the year. Could you tell me for which start and end date it does not do what you want?